# Export a matrix to flat file with one extra `names` row MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to export a matrix with the first row telling names of columns

like

```
A=
1   2  3  4
5   6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

export to matrix.txt

```
x1  x2 x3 x4
1   2  3  4
5   6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I was checking

```
dlmwrite('matrix.txt',A,'delimiter',',');
```

But how to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the '-append' option:

```
dlmwrite('matrix.txt', {'a','b','c'});
dlmwrite('matrix.txt', [1,2,3;4,5,6], '-append');
```

Comment: One more question is it possible to do `vector = (1:10)`  dlmwrite('matrix.txt', vector );` ??
and then append the matrix?

Comment: It is possible, I see no reason why it wouldn't be.